# Definition of fluid

Tags: fluid-dynamics, definition

What's [fluid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluid)?
The definition, I read isn't clear to me,it says,

> "A fluid is a substance which will yield to any continued shearing stress however small."

But, what's shearing stress? What does yield mean here?

I need a simple definition of fluid.

Comment: *I need a simple definition of fluid.* How about “something that flows”?

Comment: Something that doesn't hold a definite shape.

Comment: Yeah!But,i need an explanation of the above definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The description of shear force and stress given by @SuperCiocia is accurate. If the material shown is a solid, there may be strain as shown by the angle, but unless the shear force and stress is large enough, the strain will be limited in the case of a solid.

In the case of a fluid, the strain is not normally limited. Adjacent layers of the fluid parallel to the force F will continue to move. As @G.Smith pointed out, a fluid is something that *flows*.

Now the resistance to shear in the case of a fluid is sometimes referred to as viscosity. It is kind of related to the thickness of the fluid. Although, as indicated in the definition you gave, a substance will eventually yield (flow) to any continuing shearing stress no matter how small, it may yield very slowly. Consider thick molasses on a plate. If you tilt the plate the molasses will slide down the plate due to the shearing force of gravity. But if you tilt a very little so that the component of the gravitational force acting parallel to the plate is very little, it may take a long time for the molasses to flow.

The Heinz catsup company had a slogan regarding how thick its catsup is. The ad says, "the best things come to those who wait".

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The definition you quote essentially means "something that you can stir".

Shear stress is like pressure, though it's taken not *normal* to the surface of the fluid (that'd be pressure) but *coplanar* to the object's cross section:

[image]

In image above: force $\perp$ to $A_0$ leads to pressure (left), whereas pressure *\parallel* with $A_0$ leads to shear stress (right).

EXAMPLE: put a wooden spoon in a contained with water. Can you stir it$^\dagger$ (i.e. exert shear stress)? Yes? That's a fluid.

---

$^\dagger$: for any infinitesimally small force you put in. You will eventually also stir solids, given enough force.